# How can I set infinity as an element of a matrix in python(numpy)?

Tags: python, numpy, user-input, infinity

This is the program

```
import numpy as n
m = complex('inf')
z=n.empty([2,2] , dtype = complex)
z=n.array(input() , dtype = complex )
```

but in the console when i give 'm' as an input i get the following error massage:
'NameError: name 'm' is not defined'

Comment: i dont have any error with this code when i give 'm' as a input after executing this, also my python version 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

Infinity in python can be typed as:

float('inf') / float('-inf')

or simply as a number

1e500 (+inf)

-1e500 (-inf)